# why concurrent programs are faster?

Tags: concurrency

I've been reading a lot about concurrent programming as well as watching a lot videos online, but I still can't understand one big idea. Provided that a piece of software is written correctly and is not executed on a mulit-core processor (i.e. it runs on a single core machine) why is concurrent program runs faster than a sequential one? I keep trying to figure it out but I really can't understand.

Comment: What makes you believe that concurrent programs ran on a single core are faster than single-threaded sequential programs?

Comment: It could only run faster if at least one of the processes doesn't actually hog the CPU, so anytime it's stalling for I/O the CPU is being utilized by the rest instead of idling. That's the idea behind hyperthreading.

Comment: @ciamej I assume they teach this in schools because there is benefit to writing concurrent programs. Otherwise, I don't see a point in introducing all that complexity to synchronize the threads. I also assume if a concurrent program is incorrectly written then it will be slower than a sequential one.

Comment: @Martheen Thanks for the explanation. Can you also elaborate on hyperthreading? Is it somehow different from regular threads (say pthreads in Linux)? In other words is hyperthreading the same as threading?

Comment: Hyperthreading is done on the hardware side, which the OS is then supposed to treat a single hardware core as multiple (usually 2) virtual cores, albeit with some knowledge so if there are only two processes on dual-core CPU, you don't stick on a single core. It's different from process-level threading where the programmer explicitly write to create different threads. But the idea of "meh, you likely have idling CPU" is the key between them, that's also the reason behind setting nproc+1 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519092/what-is-the-logic-of-using-nproc-1-in-make-command

Comment: Concurrent programming is taught mainly because modern processors have multiple cores.  Near future processors will have hundreds to thousands of cores. You just need multithreaded software to harness the computing power of these processors. And you're right - multithreading is damn difficult, but it's still worth learning.

Comment: Additionally, slow IO operations are easier to handle by separate threads, even on a single core processor.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. The argument for writing concurrent code for single processors wasn't on the grounds of speed, it was about organization of tasks. It's cleaner to have different tasks handled by different threads with switching between them done by the OS, otherwise the application has to juggle the tasks itself. Data for a task can be confined to a thread and kept separate from other tasks.

Comment: This is where I'm confused. What I can't understand is how is it cleaner? Why I can't just write a single threaded code and run it? Isn't it easier to understand (hence less mistakes) code without all those synchronization calls?

Comment: @flashburn, The _state_ of each task in a multi-threaded program can be implicit in the execution context and in the local variables belonging to that thread. That makes each thread, much more like the simplistic, do-one-thing-at-a-time programs that we wrote when we were beginners. Other models of concurrency (event-driven programming, async I/O, etc.) require the state of each different task to be explicitly represented as data objects, and it requires the developer to write code that knows which state to "work on" and when.

Comment: @flashburn, Re, "Why I can't just write a single threaded program...?" You can! I wrote firmware for an industrial hygiene appliance. It had a UI—push buttons and a display. It had to promptly respond to user input. It periodically sampled various sensors. Had to respond to network packets from a remote station. Had various other async tasks. I choose to write it as a single, event-driven thread. It _could_ have been multi-threaded, and probably would have been easier to read. But, it was a safety-critical application, and my gut said, too hard to prove the multi-thread version correct.